# Handling data from Python socket recv

Tags: python, sockets, recv

I'm using Python 2.7 sockets to receive data:

```
data = self.socket.recv(4096)
```

How do I go about retrieving the first unsigned short from the data? The data looks like this:

```
>>> print repr(data) 
'\x00\x053B2D4C24\x00\x00\x01\x00...'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by unsigned short you mean two bytes, just do:

```
data[:2]
```

If you know and expect a certain chunk size of data to parse, you can use the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) library.

Comment: Yea that's the obvious answer. There might be a more elegant way of doing it but for now I'm going with a variation of what you have.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
s = struct.Struct('H')
num = int('0x' + ''.join(x for x in repr(packet[:s.size]) if x.isdigit()), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but thought I'd post a better solution anyway:

```
value, = struct.unpack('H', data[:2])
```

Note the `,` usage in order to correctly unpack the 1-tuple that is returned.